# problems with InternalsVisibleTo Attribute

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
namespace ConectorV2
{
    [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Pruebas")]
    internal static class Utilidades
    {
        internal static string extraerCadenaDeConexion()
        {
            return extraerCadenaDeConexion(new XElement());
        }
        internal static string extraerCadenaDeConexion(XElement documento)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the Pruebas project:

```
namespace Pruebas.ConectorV2.Cliente
{
    [TestFixture]
    class ModuloExtraerCadenaDeConexion
    {
        [Test]
        public void devuelveCadenaSolicitada()
        {
            var mock = new MockRepository();
            var appSettings =
                XElement.Parse(
                    @"<appSettings>
                                <setting key='dbtype' value='SQLSERVER' />
                                <setting key='SQLSERVER' value='prueba' />
                            </appSettings>");
            Assert.That(ConectorV2.Utilidades.extraerCadenaDeConexion(appSettings), Is.EqualTo("prueba"));
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error on compile:

The type or namespace name 'Utilidades' does not exist in the namespace Pruebas.ConectorV2' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The assembly is correctly referenced in my pruebas project and I read on msdn that the default assembly name for a project is the project name... what am I missing?

Comment: Have you applied a strong name signature to either or both of the assemblies?

Comment: no, though I was under the impression I didn't need to

Comment: ok, so I signed both assemblies and now it says 'Conector.Utilidades' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: You don't need to sign them.  However, if you do, you need to use the strong name in the InternalsVisibleTo attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use assembly level attributes on classes! Just do so:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Pruebas")]
namespace ConectorV2
{
    internal static class Utilidades
    { /* ... */
```

it should work

Comment: yeah I just found that out. funny that skeet's book c# in depth puts the attribute on the class. I guess the c# dev team got it wrong then =P.

Comment: may be they didn't place the class in the namespace; if so, then it's acceptable to place an assembly attribute above the class